# Unable to use template file as a template for the component in Liferay angular portlet

Tags: angular, typescript, liferay, portlet, liferay-7

**Unable to use the template file as a template for the component in Liferay angular portlet.** The same syntax is working fine with the plain angular application.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    /*
     * I've tried to pass template file path as below but it wasn't worked
     * templateUrl: './app.component.html'
     * templateUrl: './app.component'
     * templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
     * templateUrl: 'app.component'
     */
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

***app.component.html***

```
<h1>app component loaded using template file.</h1>
```

Below is my environment detail

- **OS** : windows
- **Liferay** : liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.3.2-ga3
- **node** : v8.12.0
- **angular/cli** : ^1.6.7
- **angular/compiler-cli** : ^5.0.0
- **liferay-npm-bundler** : 2.18.2
- **typescript** : 2.4.2

[image: Unable to use the template file as a template for the component in Liferay angular portlet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from Liferay forum : https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/message/103176934#_com_liferay_message_boards_web_portlet_MBPortlet_message_106877078

According to the description, I've updated templateUrl path as below and it works fine.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: '/o/student-crud-portlet/lib/app/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: Just a note: the "student-crud-portlet" has to be replaced with the name of your portlet. You can find this out by opening angular-loader.ts and search for the first argument of the function "Liferay.Loader.require()".